# glClientWaitSync causes segmentation fault on windows

Tags: windows, opengl, synchronization

More specifically I have two threads.

The first one:

```
ev_wait_vsync = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "wait_vsync");
...
printf("paint\n");
sync = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
SetEvent(ev_wait_vsync);
```

And second one, created by the first:

```
WaitForSingleObject(ev_wait_vsync, INFINITE);
printf("start vsync\n");
glClientWaitSync(sync, GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, UINT64_MAX);
printf("end sync\n");
```

This causes segfault. The output is:

```
paint
start vsync
```

so the problem is with `glClientWaitSync`, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so the problem is with glClientWaitSync, but why?

Because a OpenGL context can be active in only one thread at a time. Multithreaded OpenGL operation is a delicate thing and should be avoided where possible.

What happens in your case is, that `glClientWaitSync` must be obtained via `wglGetProcAddress` and the function pointers this function yields are only valid in the context *and the thread* which was active when the function pointer was retrieved (this is a caveat of WGL, not OpenGL). Other context, other thread, and you need to obtain a fresh/different function pointer. Also the OpenGL sync object works only with the context is has been created from.

On a side note: `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` has *nothing* to do with V-Sync! It may happen as well when a `glReadPixels` or a `glCopyTexImage2D` comes along, which cause an implicit flush.

Comment: vsync is occured because of `SwapBuffers` before `glFenceSync` which I not included in code fragment.

Comment: @nshy: glWaitClientSync with a GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT will trigger a flush. So this clearly doesn't what you probably expect. See http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sync_Objects

Comment: Mmm, flush is ok. SwapBuffers will trigger a flush two. I hoped that SwapBuffers before fence would be considered complete when actual buffer swap on vsync occured.

Comment: @nshy: With V-Sync enabled SwapBuffers will block until the V-Sync happened. With V-Sync disabled SwapBuffers returns as soon as the implicit flush is done. Note: if you're still trying to surpass the display refresh rate: Why? Consider the time you're not spending rendering as a precious gift of CPU time.

Comment: AFAIK SwapBuffers should not to block until complete with vsync due to asynchronous nature of open gl spec. That question was of theoretical interest) What I trying to archive is animation so that I render a frame when I need to after another vsync. If I keep render in message loop I found SwapBuffers ultimately comes at 60 Hz, but it blocks after some time, first calls are not. I guess it blocks when GPU command queue is fullfilled.

Comment: @nshy: Most OpenGL operation is not asynchronous but concurrent. This is a very important difference! Anyway, if V-Sync is enabled, then SwapBuffers *will block* until the vertical retrace; the details are actually rather complicated, because this touches the innards of the graphics and windowing infrastructure of the system (the SwapBuffers call is *not* part of OpenGL). But due to the architecture of most graphics systems the buffer swap always block to the very moment the actual swap is performed, which is normally done at the moment of vertical retrace.